# Creating new layer from another one and adding new fields with Qgis processing python scripts?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, windows-10

I'm developing a script in processing for personal use and have some difficulties with the Qgis API. I bought The Pygis Programmers guide . It has been useful but I have had some difficulties in defining processes. I just want to create a script that writes me the same shapefile , add two fields and then calculate the ratio perimeter area.

This is my code:

```
##testes=group
##Ratio =name
##layer=vector
##output_file=output vector

from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QGis, QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsFields
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter

vectorLayer = processing.getObject(layer)

provider = vectorLayer.dataProvider()

writer = VectorWriter(output, None, provider.fields(),
                  provider.geometryType(), vectorLayer.crs())

features = processing.features(vectorLayer)
for feat in features:
writer.addFeature(feat)

del writer

#add fields 
New_layer= processing.getObject(layer)
fields=QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField('AREA', QVariant.Double,'',20,3))
fields.append(QgsField('PERIMETER', QVariant.Double,'',20,3))
fields.append(QgsField('RATIO', QVariant.Double,'',20,3)) #Perimeter/Area   (RATIO)
writer = processing.VectorWriter(output_file, None, fields.toList(),
                              QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, New_layer.crs())
del writer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need two instances of `writer` so you can remove the first one. I've modified your code so that the output takes the fields of the input and adds the new fields you defined:

```
##testes=group
##Ratio =name
##layer=vector
##output_file=output vector

from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QGis, QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsFields
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter

vectorLayer = processing.getObject(layer)
provider = vectorLayer.dataProvider()

New_layer= processing.getObject(layer)
fields = QgsFields()
fields = provider.fields()
fields.append(QgsField('AREA', QVariant.Double,'',20,3))
fields.append(QgsField('PERIMETER', QVariant.Double,'',20,3))
fields.append(QgsField('RATIO', QVariant.Double,'',20,3))

writer = processing.VectorWriter(output_file, None, fields.toList(),
                              QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, New_layer.crs())

features = processing.features(vectorLayer)
for feat in features:
    writer.addFeature(feat)

del writer
```